# AngularJS directive click can only be called once

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am working on a directive to show a modal. It works the first time through but the second time or anytime after the, the click no longer works. The code looks like this:

```
<li><a href="http://example.com/JohnDoe" profile-modal="JohnDoe">JohnDoe</li>

EngagementApp.directive('profileModal', ['$compile', 'Request', '$modal', '$q',
```

function($compile, Request, $modal, $q) {

```
return {
    restrict : 'A',
    link : function(scope, element, attrs) {

        element.bind('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            scope.modal = { 
                username : attrs.profileModal,
                url : main_site_url
            };

            var modalPromise = $modal({template: '/templates/profile.html', persist: true, show: false, backdrop: 'static', scope: scope});

            $q.when(modalPromise).then(function(modalEl) {
                modalEl.modal('show');
            });

        });

    }
};
```

}]);

How can I get the click to work several times and not just the first time? The framework I'm using for the modal is angularstrap. http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/

Comment: The first time I click the link with the directive, it execute the code inside element.bind. But if I click it again, the code inside element.bind no longer is called. I tested it by inputing a console.log('Test') message inside the element.bind function.

Comment: Correction, the code is executing, just but not the modal. I added to console log to test.

Comment: Since no one knows what framework you use for the model dialog, no one is able to help you.

Comment: I'm using angular strap. http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/

Comment: I believe you need to use the promise returned by your $modal() call (don't forget to inject the `$q` service). Something like:

    $q.when($modal({...})).then(function (modalHandle) {
        modalHandle.modal('show');
    });

Comment: Same result.Updated code above.